# Access levels in swift

Tags: swift

access level confusion in swift.

I was experimenting with swift access level for class and their data member and subclasses.
and below code worked fine in playground without any error.

i thought we can only give <= access level to class data members. (ie. if class is internal then its data member or functions should only be internal or private or file private.)

but below code work without any error in playground.

```
1.
public struct Student{
    private var studentId : String
}
2.
open class Employee{
    open var EmployeeId : String?
}
3.
private class CompanyEmployee : Employee{

}
4.
internal class Animal{
    public var no_of_legs : Int?
    open var name : String?
}
5.
fileprivate class Shape{
    public var shape_type : String?
}
6.
private class Point{
    public var x : Int?
    public var y : Int?
}
7.
fileprivate class SpecificPoint : Point{

}
```

Comment: first 3 looks fine. don't know why rest of the stuffs didn't throw any error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: for eg. is it possible to have internal class with public data member / properties/ function ? OR is it possible to have public data member / properties / function inside private class ?

Comment: A property can't have a higher access than its type, so not the type it is part of but the type it is defined as. So for instance x and y can be declared public in `Point` sine their type, Int, is also public. The accessor on `Point` is not relevant here. If you on the other side add a `Point` property to `Shape` then it can't be public but must be `fileprivate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default access level is `internal`. If you specify a narrower access level (`fileprivate` or `private`) on your type, the access level of its members can only be as wide as the type's access level. But you don't want to have to write that narrower access level on every member of the type.

That is, **you want to be able to write this**:

```
// Only specify narrower access for the type, not for the type's members.
fileprivate struct Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}
```

**You don't want to have to write this:**

```
// Specify narrower access for the type and its members.
fileprivate struct Point {
    fileprivate var x: Double
    fileprivate var y: Double
}
```

But the default access level is `internal`. So, Swift automatically “clamps” a member's access level to the narrower of the member's specified or default access level and its container's access level.

Yes, there are other ways Swift could handle this (for example, by only clamping when the unwritten default `internal` was used), but this is how it was implemented. It can't be changed now without breaking existing source code.

---

It is worth noting that a type or a member can have a narrow access level but in fact be more accessible through a protocol conformance. Consider this example:

```
protocol P {
    var x: Int { get }
}

fileprivate struct S: P {
    var x: Int
}

func make() -> P { return S(x: 100) }
```

In this example, `make` and `P` have the default `internal` access level, while the type `S` explicitly has `fileprivate` access level and its member `x` has effective `fileprivate` access level.

However, from any other file in the module, you can call `make()`. You'll get an `S` back, but you can only treat it is a `P`. Since it is a `P`, you can read its `x` property, even though the `x` property of `S` has effective access level `fileprivate`.

Comment: i am confused, can you tell me what will be access level of x and y in below code:

private class Point{
    public var x : Int?
    public var y : Int?
}

Comment: The effective access level of `x` and `y` is `private`.

Comment: I think the point that is being implied, but maybe not directly expressed, is that is it ok to declare a sub component (be it method, type or property) with a more open access level than it's parent and it will not error - as in your `Point` above - but the actual access level of those component will be the most restrictive in their hierarchy - so your `x` and `y` will inherit `private` from their parent struct.